# Securing vagrant box and adding new user with a password

Tags: debian, vagrant, vagrant-provision

I'm provisioning a vagrant box based on `bento/debian-9.6`

My goal is to install `rstudio-server` and for the network to be bridged for remote accessibility.

The issue I'm having is that `rstudio-server` uses [PAM authentication](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/221303588-What-is-my-username-on-my-RStudio-Server-)  This means that the default `vagrant` user has access to `rstudio-server` with the password `vagrant`.

What is the best way to add a new user (e.g. `rstudiouser`) secured with a password in the context of a vagrant provision?  I found a way to [add a user using an ssh key](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167919/adding-ubuntu-user-to-vagrant-ubuntu-instance) but this doesn't work for me as the `rstudio-server` needs the user to have a password.  Though I'll need my user to have sFTP access to the vagrant box so I'll need to create an ssh key also.

What is the best way to secure the server since it will be available publicly since the `vagrant` and `root` user passwords and ssh keys are publicly known?

Below is my current provisioning script

```
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
     export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
     sudo apt-get update
     sudo apt-get -y install apt-transport-https dirmngr ca-certificates software-properties-common gnupg2
     sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-key 'E19F5F87128899B192B1A2C2AD5F960A256A04AF'
     sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian stretch-cran35/'
     sudo apt-get update
     sudo apt-get -y install r-base r-base-dev gdebi-core libcurl4-gnutls-dev libxml2-dev libssl-dev build-essential gdebi-core git
     wget https://download2.rstudio.org/server/debian9/x86_64/rstudio-server-1.2.1335-amd64.deb
     sudo gdebi --n rstudio-server-1.2.1335-amd64.deb
     sudo bash -c "echo 'www-port=80' >> /etc/rstudio/rserver.conf"
     sudo rstudio-server restart
     sudo R -e "install.packages(c('devtools', 'Seurat'), repos = 'https://cran.rstudio.com/', dep = TRUE)"
     SHELL
```